# Fallback picture for <PICTURE>

Tags: html

Is `<PICTURE>` officially in HTML5?  I can't find it in w3schools.com.

Assuming it is official, is the source attribute of the fallback `<img>` element `src` or `srcset`.  I am seeing some web sites using `srcset` and they don't work in any version of IE, but `src` works in IE.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can see an (unofficial) overview of browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture).

**The `<img>` element *must* be included, and this has the side-effect of offering a fall-back option.**

The picture element, by necessity, must have an `<img>` tag inside it, alongside the `<source>` elements. This has the side-effect of providing a fall-back option, but is also necessary to provide the base image and metadata (especially to provide the required `alt` attribute). The `<source>` elements merely override the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag (under specified circumstances).

Here is an example of the picture element, used properly. This example comes from the [Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

**The `src` attribute should *always* be included, even if you use the `srcset` attribute in addition.**

The `srcset` attribute is (from what I understand) an "older" technique of defining sources for different resolutions. It does not use standard-syntax media queries or have the other flexibilities afforded by using the `<picture>` and `<source>` elements ([although Chris Coyier of CSS-tricks disagrees with me here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)), but may be supported by some browsers which don't support the newer standard. Including the `srcset` attribute on your `<img>` tag might be desirable, but, in these cases, you still need to include the `src` attribute as well (which provides a default when none of the `srcset` files are appropriate, and provides a fall-back for browsers that don't support `srcset`). All image tags always need `src` and `alt` attribute -- these are required attributes for the `<img>` tag.

A valid example of the `<picture>` tag, including the `srcset` attribute as a fall-back, and the `src` attribute as a worst-case-scenario fall-back, is below.

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" srcset="mdn-logo.png 2x" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

---

**This [Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/14/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/) gives a much more in-depth analysis of the different responsive images techniques and when to use each one.**

---

*Aside: Please don't trust W3Schools as an official source. W3Schools chose a name that is similar to W3C (the World Wide Web Consortium), but they are not, in fact, related to the official standards body. From their [about](http://www.w3schools.com/about/default.asp) page: "The site derives its name from the World Wide Web (W3), but is not affiliated with the W3C."*

Comment: Thanks. My question was should it be `<img src='...'>` or `<img srcset='...'>`.  From your answer, I guess the `<img>` has to be something old browsers can understand, so `src`.  One website was using `srcset` and I got confused.

Comment: @OldGeezer ah, i missed that in my answer. i've added a section to address that and included a link to a very in-depth article. basically, you should *always* have an `src` attribute on your image, even if you also have an `srcset` attribute.

Comment: `srcset` is NOT a fallback mechanism, it is used to specify higher-quality images for your users who have high-resolution displays, without penalizing the users who don’t, meaning images defined in `srcset` will not be loaded at all if your viewport is smaller then defined. Also it is a webkit alternative to `source media` defined by w3c standard that is still under construction but is already documented in 5.1 nightly doc i linked in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for stating that the `<img>` element must be included.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `<picture>` tag is part of html5 and according to documentation, its fallback is `<img src=... >` which will work even in very old browsers.

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 64em)" src="high-res.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" src="med-res.jpg">
   <source src="low-res.jpg">
   <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="This picture loads on non-supporting browsers.">
   <p>Accessible text.</p>
</picture>
```

Its also worth noting that other solutions, such as the `srcset` attribute, are also being discussed and are starting to see support. The `srcset` attribute was  implemented in Webkit a while ago. However `srcset` attribute is not used for fallback but allows you to specify higher-quality images for your users who have high-resolution displays, without penalizing the users who don’t.

Comment: _"according to documentation"_ Got a source?

Comment: 4.8.3 The picture element of the [Html 5.1 Nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-picture-element)
The picture element is a container which provides multiple sources to its contained img element to allow authors to declaratively control or give hints to the user agent about which image resource to use, based on the screen pixel density, viewport size, image format, and other factors.

Comment: i can't find anything that indicates that it would be appropriate to put a paragraph tag inside a picture element. can you address that in your answer? (and also add your sources to your answer for posterity's sake -- comments get deleted after a while.)

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I saw in some blog that the `<p>` is the equivalent of the `alt` of `img`. Like you said, it is a living experimental standard...

Comment: @Woodrow Barlow im pretty sure there is no additional documentation needed, all you need to understand is that you basically can put any tag within, and old browsers will interpret em as they would usually ignoring new tags, we might be going offtopic with this as there are exceptions especially if nesting picture tags, but that is a matter of another topic.

Comment: The `p` there is invalid and will be rendered for everyone, whether the image is shown or not. Remove and just use `alt`.