# <picture> html5 support and fallback for older browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser

I'm thinking about using the html `<picture>` element in a sliding carousel to optimise load times for a webpage.

I'm worried it does not have enough [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=picture) though as I will need it to work in IE10.

Is there any other fallback method I can use for it to work in older browsers, or at least render something that will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fallback picture for <PICTURE>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186257/fallback-picture-for-picture)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picturefill to handle this https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

With it you an use the picture element as well as source sets and size attributes. It's been a while since I had to use this particular polyfill but in the past it worked fine.